# removing sidebar - spree commerce

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, spree

I'm trying to remove the sidebar from my Spree app.

In my `apps/override/remove_sidebar.rb`:

```
Deface::Override.new(
  :virtual_path =>"layouts/spree_application",
  :name => "remove_sidebar",
  :remove => "[data-hook='homepage_sidebar_navigation']")
```

Is there anything else that I am missing?  The server detects the override, but nothing happens.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Fixed my own problem:

In `apps/override/remove_sidebar.rb`:

```
Deface::Override.new(
  :virtual_path =>"spree/layouts/spree_application",
  :name => "remove_sidebar",
  :remove => "aside#sidebar")
```

Comment: In Spree 2.1.4, I had to use `virtual_path: 'spree/shared/_sidebar'`.

Answer (score 0):

[data-hook='homepage_sidebar_navigation'] doesn't appear in layouts/spree_application

This appears in the following files and the override works fine there:
core/app/views/spree/home/index.html.erb
core/app/views/spree/products/index.html.erb